# Is there a way to "subscribe" to someone's question?

Tags: support, status-completed, bookmarks

I found another user's question and I would like to know what answers are given. Is there a way to "subscribe" to a question so as to get informed of answers to it? I know I could just bookmark it and check back now and then, but I am busy and tend to forget...
Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen the "Question Feed" link at the bottom right of every question?  (There's even one for this question!)

Comment: Cool, an RSS for that specific question. Would be nice to have that placed somewhere obvious. This is a great feature because it allows non-members to follow questions.

Comment: Place the RSS icon below the favourite button?

Comment: SaultDon, please consider posting that suggestion as a new meta thread to get the attention of the SE team: it sounds like one they would want to hear.

Comment: +1 for @SaultDon's comment.  I didn't even know the feature existed.  Having it in a more "obvious" location would be a great improvement.

Comment: @whuber Done. Interesting to note, that because your comment doesn't include the @ or maybe the comma after my name, that I never got notified of your comment. I did with Ryans.

Answer (score 5):

You can click the symbol under the voting arrows to "favorite" it. Then you get a message at the top of the screen when there are new answers.