# Can GIS.se place the RSS feed button for questions somewhere more obvious?

Tags: feature-request, design

When I read the question "[Is there a way to subscribe to someones question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/766/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-to-someones-question)" I discovered there is an RSS feed button!

But unfortunately, it is tucked away in the bottom right of the page.

This is useful feature as it allows non-members to follow any specific question they like without needing to register or login.

It would be nice to see this button in a more obvious place instead of hiding in the bottom right.

I found that I never actually scroll to the bottom of the page when I am reading questions and answers. Once I see the "Your Answer" box, my scrolling stops there unless I have an awesome opinion.

Comment: I think this capability is at least as important as the "favorite question" feature (the 5 pointed star under the up/down vote control).  Maybe it could go right under the star?